# javax inject on a Resteasy service not working on Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, cdi, resteasy

I have this Restful service:

```
@Service
public class MyRESTServiceImpl implements MyRESTService {

    @Inject
    private Helper helper;

    public MyRESTServiceImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public List<Something> getThings() {
          return helper.getThings(); // NPE here!
    }
}
```

The problem here is that when getThings is accessed through `/api/getThings`, although the method is invoked the helper is not injected. Whereas on the other parts of the app it injected properly. I am missing some annotation for this `MyRESTServiceImpl`?

Comment: And you're using CDI? What is `@Service`? a custom annotation you've added?

Comment: Yes CDI, I have also tried to use `@ApplicationScoped`, the `@Service` is https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ERRAI/Bus+Services

Comment: Errai's service annotation is not a CDI qualifier.  The two are not linked.  You must use Errai's IOC to use `@Service`